# Calculating Operating Costs to give a fixed profit margin

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We are importing sales data from a company we just purchased.
We want to calculate the logistics value so that the profit margin is 13%.

We have the following rules in our system:

```
Profit = SalesValue - OriginalPrice - LogisticsValue
CostValue = OriginalPrice + LogisticsValue

ProfitMargin = Profit/CostValue * 100
             = (SalesValue - OriginalPrice - LogisticsValue) / (OriginalPrice + LogisticsValue) * 100
```

If SalesValue = $1000, OriginalPrice = $750 and ProfitMargin = 13 and LogisitcsValue = LV then

```
             13 = ((1000-750-LV)/(750+LV)) * 100
                = (250 - LV) / (750+LV) * 100
0.13 * (750+LV) = (250 - LV)
    0.13LV + LV = 250
```

How can I find the value of LV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula you can use generally.

LV = ( 100*(SV - OP) - PM*OP )/ (100 + PM)

In your example, you would get 134.96.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your last step there. It should read:

$0.13(750+LV)=250-LV \Rightarrow 0.13(750)+0.13LV=250-LV
\Rightarrow 1.13LV=250-0.13(750)
\Rightarrow LV \approx 134.955$.

Comment: Thanks. Typo when putting it into the site. 134.96 was the answer I got

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out what I was missing.

```
0.13LV + LV = 1.13LV
```

So

```
0.13LV + LV = 250
     1.13LV = 250
         LV = 250/1.13
         LV = 134.96 (to 2 decimal places)
```